# Equivalent C# / SQLite command for the PHP command mysql_insert_id()?

Tags: c#, mysql, sqlite

I'm used to using the command "mysql_insert_id()" in PHP to return the id of the last line inserted into my database.

Is there an equivalent command in SQLite in C#?

Thanks!

-Adeena

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SELECT last_insert_rowid()

Also check out this post.  It explains in detail how to adjust a DataAdapter to retrieve the last insert row ID.

http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/p/134/465.aspx#465